# Excel 2013 repeating equation on all rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, equations

How do we repeat an equation on all the rows? Endlessly, as we enter data in other columns of the row, I want equation to calculate. Technically creating a new row everyday but I want to calculate as I begin entering data for that row.

I have 5 columns: A = Date. B, C and D = Are used to enter daily data. E = Equation (B+C-D). So every day I will have a user enter data in B, C, and D. I want the date and the equation to come up as soon as they enter the data in B, C, or D.

Comment: Just drag it down the column..

Comment: Is your question about how to get the same equation in every row, or how to have pre-populated equations not display anything until there is input?

Comment: im assuming the prepopulated equations. my sheet is protected and the unlocked cells i call the "data entry" cells. I want a user to enter the data and when the first cell is entered with data i want the equation to display a number. I want this to occur on all the rows of the sheet. Thanks!

Comment: The above information, in your comment, is important to share in your question. Details help us help you. What have you attempted so far? Can you give us an example how your data is set up?

Comment: i have about 5 columns and an equation on the far right. =(B+C-D). In column A i have dates. So every day i will have a user enter data in b,c,and d i want the date and the equation to come up as soon as they enter the data in B,C, or D

Comment: You could probably use a table.  That would automatically add formulas (and formatting) as entries are made in new rows.

Comment: is there a way we can have the table continuous and not a fixed number of rows?

Comment: The point with tables is that you don't need to make it continuous, because they expand automatically. If you fill your sheet down to gigantic proportions, the file size will be huge. Tables that are just the correct size at each moment are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Type the following nested function in cell E2 then past it into the entire column:

```
=IF(AND(B2="",C2="",D2=""),"",B2+C2-D2)
```

Same with the Date for column A. Type the following nested function in cell A3:

```
=IF(AND(B3="",C3="",D3=""),"",A2+1)
```

Past it into the entire column, and type the first date in cell A2.